# Where can I obtain a glass bow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am level 26 and I would like to obtain a glass bow but I don't know where I can get one. I don't mind stealing it because my pick pocketing and sneak skills are quite high.

Also I have a lot of money so that isn't a problem either.

Comment: Can't you craft one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glass Bows can be looted from enemies, and they have the highest chances of occurring between levels 27 and 32.  Above that, you're more likely to see things that are Ebony, and much more rarely, Daedric.

You can also purchase them randomly from vendors, with I believe the best odds of finding one occurring around the same levels.

You can also just make your own - if your Smithing skill is 70 or more, and you have the [Glass Smithing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing) perk, you can take 2 [Refined Malachite](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Malachite) and 1 [Refined Moonstone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elven) to a blacksmith workshop and make one from scratch.  This perk also allows you to improve your glass weapons and armor, which considerably improves the damage output of the Glass Bow.

As far as guaranteed loot, I'm not aware of any besides the [Glass Bow of the Stag Prince](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Bow_of_the_Stag_Prince) which is part of the Dragonborn expansion.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glass_Bow#Glass_Bow)

> Glass Weapons are the third-best weapons, behind Daedric and Ebony weapons. They appear in leveled lists starting at level 27 (enchanted varieties at level 28).

So you should grind a little more to have a chance of finding one eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You can steal one from the treasury in markarth, steal the key to the gate, pick the safe

Comment: Is that bow always there, or is it levelled loot?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yeah it's random and leveled. The one asking is just one level away to loot glass bows.

Answer (score -5):

i found a glass war hammer in haemars shame or something but when my brother went there, he got a glass bow. if you want something made of glass (you have a chance to get a glass bow) go to falkreath, talk to the blacksmith, if he asks you if you've seen a dog say no then intimidate him when he says he will give you fresh meat if you complete a quest (he will give you meat if you want), find barbas (the dog), go to haemar's shame and when you get to haemar's shrine or something then kill the spider, proceed until you see a statue and look in all ash piles there will be something made of glass (if you find nothing made of glass, look in all the bodies) if you want a good helmet or a kind of good axe talk to the statue and he will give you quest complete the quest and he will tell you to kill barbas with the axe (the rueful axe) or you dont and you get a good helmet (masque of clavicus vile)

its your choice to kill barbas or not

Comment: There's nothing special about Haemar's Shame. It's just one of many, many places with randomised loot that might give you glass gear once you're the right level for random glass loot.